# Autenticación con Dropwizard

Tags: java, autenticación, dropwizard

Soy novata con Java y Dropwizard. Tengo una app de Ionic que realiza una llamada de Ajax a un servidor DropWizard para realizar una autenticación básica (Basic Authentication) y funciona bien.

**UserResources.java**

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResources {

    @Timed
    @GET
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(@Auth User user) {

        RestServiceResponse<TokenResponse> res =new RestServiceResponse<TokenResponse>();
        TokenResponse token = TokenResponse.createToken(user);
        res.setObject(token); 
        res.setStatus("OK");
        return Response.ok().entity(res).build();
    }
}
```

**MyApliccation.java**

```
//Register class UserAuthenticator
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                .setAuthenticator(new UserAuthenticator(configuration)).setRealm("AUTH REALM").buildAuthFilter()));

        environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
```

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Principal {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(Integer id, String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all documents related to  a user
     * 
     * @return A collection of Documents 
     */
    public Collection<Document> getDocuments(){

        return null;

    }



}
```

Esta authenticacion me devuelve un token, y lo que quiero poder realizar el resto de llamadas al servidor con este token, para verificar si el usuario es el mismo. He visto en la documentación de Dropwizard que puedo crear "Multiple Principals and Authenticators" pero no entiendo como voy a diferenciarlos a la hora de llamarlos. Si alguien pudiera indicarme como puedo implementar un filtro o alguna otra cosa que intercepte todas las llamadas menos la de "/user/login" y compruebe el token... he visto ejemplos en internet, pero ninguno con un login de username/password al principio, todos envían directamente el token.

Quiero llamar a una nueva funcion que me devuelva documentos, pero solo si el usuario es el mismo que se h aautenticado, ahora tengo puesta una autenticacion básica que vuelve a comprobar ususario y contraseña, pero querri que fuera con el token.

```
@Timed
    @GET
    @Path("/documets")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDocuments(@Auth User user) {

        RestServiceResponse<Document> res =new RestServiceResponse<Document>();
        Collection<Document> documents = user.getDocuments();
        res.setObjectList(documents); 
        res.setStatus("OK");
        return Response.ok().entity(res).build();       
    }
```